# Отсортировать статьи по дате

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, нужно отсортировать статьи по дате при нажатии на кнопку **Sort by date**, но без jQuery, всяких плагинов и т.д., исключительно на Javascript.

Код:

```js
var url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/movies/30.json?api-key=';

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText).results;
        var posts = data.map(mapToPost);

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = getPostsTemplate(posts);
    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();

function mapToPost(post) {
    return {
        link: post.url,
        img: post.media[0] ? post.media[0]["media-metadata"][2].url : null,
        description: post.abstract,
        title: post.title,
        date: post.published_date
    };
}

function getPostsTemplate(posts) {
    return posts.reduce(function (tmpl, post) {
        tmpl += '<div class="post">\n' +
                    '<h2 class="post-title">' + post.title + '</h2>\n' +
                    '<img src=' + post.img + '>\n' +
                    '<p class="post-description">' + post.description + '</p>\n' +
                    '<a class="post-link" href=' + post.link + '>Read more</a>\n' +
                    '<p class="post-date"> Publication date: ' + post.date + '</p>\n' +
                    '<hr> <br> <br>\n' +
                '</div>\n';

        var arr = [];
        arr.push(post.date);
        console.log(arr);

        return tmpl;
    }, '');
}
```

```html
<button>Sort by date</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Удалил ваш api-key из ответа)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаги.

Сохраняем массив с данными в переменную, которую потом будем сортировать.

Сортируем с помощью метода `sort`.

Показываем результат.

```js
var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/ee48c8b9fd14508ae5afa8f997dbdd81/raw/e1722f1c649af591bb3d3bea2e23909b5c50e8b9/Article%2520for%2520nytimes';

//Для сохранение исходного массива
var posts = [];
// Флаг для убывания\возрастания
var isDesc = false;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText).results;
    posts = data.map(mapToPost);
    //Сортируем по возрастанию при первом показе
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = getPostsTemplate(sortByField(posts, 'date', isDesc));
  }
};

xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();

function sortClick() {
  isDesc = !isDesc;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = getPostsTemplate(sortByField(posts, 'date', isDesc));
}

// Сортируем массив по данному полю
function sortByField(array, field, isDesc) {
  var sign = isDesc ? -1 : 1;

  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[field] > b[field]) return sign;
    else if (a[field] === b[field]) return 0
    else return -sign;
  });
}

function mapToPost(post) {
  return {
    link: post.url,
    img: post.media[0] ? post.media[0]["media-metadata"][2].url : null,
    description: post.abstract,
    title: post.title,
    date: post.published_date,
    date_: new Date(post.published_date) // поле нужно для правильной сортировки
  };
}

function getPostsTemplate(posts) {
  return posts.reduce(function(tmpl, post) {
    tmpl += '<div class="post">\n' +
      '<h2 class="post-title">' + post.title + '</h2>\n' +
      '<img src=' + post.img + '>\n' +
      '<p class="post-description">' + post.description + '</p>\n' +
      '<a class="post-link" href=' + post.link + '>Read more</a>\n' +
      '<p class="post-date"> Publication date: ' + post.date + '</p>\n' +
      '<hr> <br> <br>\n' +
      '</div>\n';

    return tmpl;
  }, '');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortClick()">Sort by date</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Готовый код вам врядли кто-то напишет. Но у меня была бы последовательность действий такая:

1) Забираю все объекты с API, кладу их в массив

2) При помощи reduce отсортировываю объекты по дате.

Пример кода:

```
 let arr= [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: "2018-02-18"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: "2018-02-06"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: "2018-02-22"
  }
];


let newArr = arr.reduce(function(result, item) {
  const val = item['date'];

  result[val] = result[val] || [];
  result[val].push(item)
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(newArr);
```